# Matlab read Strings as arrays for transposition cipher

Tags: matlab

I need to use Matlab for implementing a transposition algorithm.
Let's say you have a variable called 
`plaintext='qwerty........zxcv'` (doesn't matter what the text really is, but the alphabet should containd A-Z and space characters) 
and a variable called

```
lof = length(plaintext) %. (the size of the message)
```

Also, you have the following transposition(stored in variable tp):

```
1 2 3 4 5
5 3 1 4 2

tp = '5 3 1 4 2';
```

I thought of using a variable buffer and `ltp = length(tp)`.
In variable buffer I would read `ltp` characters a time, till I got no characters in the plaintext. 
So, I need some suggestion how to read `ltp` letters from plaintext at a time.
Also, if the 'buffer' variable has let's say 5 chars, then I should use a 'for' loop for interchanging the char on the respective index? Or there is another better solution for letter permutation.

I would very much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, you split up your text into 5 character chunks.  You then perform a permutation of these chunks by using the transposition variable, `tp` and reassemble these chunks so that you create a ciphertext to encrypt your plaintext.  Therefore, characters at positions 1 - 5 for each chunk are rearranged such that:

```
Source --> Target
   1         5
   2         3
   3         1
   4         4
   5         2
```

---

Based on what I see, let's start with the most simplest way.  You can use a `for` loop as you suggested.  Use a loop and create values that start at index 1 and skip over a certain amount of characters - which is equal to the length of `tp`.  You would then use these indices to slice into your character array and perform a permutation of the characters.  Make sure you create an output array that is the same size as the input, then do the permutation for each chunk.

Something like this:

```
%// Define plain text
plaintext = 'hello my name is ray nice to meet you';

%// Define permutation vector
tp = [5 3 1 4 2];
ltp = numel(tp); %// Define length of transposition
lp = numel(plaintext); %// Length of plaintext

%// Declare ciphertext array
ciphertext = char(zeros(1,lp));

%// Pad the array with spaces so that when we grab chunks, we don't
%// go out of bounds
plaintext = [plaintext 32*ones(1,ltp*ceil(lp/ltp) - lp)];

%// For each chunk...
for idx = 1 : ltp : lp
    %// Get the plain text chunk
    tx = plaintext(idx : idx+ltp-1);

    %// Permute the chunk and place back into output array
    ciphertext(idx : idx+ltp-1) = tx(tp);
end
```

So the plain text is:

```
plaintext = 'hello my name is ray nice to meet you';
```

The output I get is:

```
ciphertext = 

olhleny  miea myrsa ei cnmo  tyte e  o u
```

---

A more vectorized solution (in case you're curious) would be to reshape the array so that the number of rows matches the length of the transposition vector and the number of columns is the number of chunks that decompose the text, once you pad the array so that we don't go out of bounds.  This way, each column represents a unique chunk.  You would then permute the rows of this matrix and reshape it back.

Something like this:

```
%// Define plain text
plaintext = 'hello my name is ray nice to meet you';

%// Define permutation vector
tp = [5 3 1 4 2];
ltp = numel(tp); %// Define length of transposition
lp = numel(plaintext); %// Length of plaintext

%// Pad the array with spaces so that when we grab chunks, we don't
%// go out of bounds
plaintext = [plaintext 32*ones(1,ltp*ceil(lp/ltp) - lp)];

%// Begin vectorized solution
ciphertext = reshape(plaintext, ltp, []);
ciphertext = reshape(ciphertext(tp, :), 1, []);
```

We still get what we see in our first attempt:

```
ciphertext =

olhleny  miea myrsa ei cnmo  tyte e  o u
```